# NSBundle pathForResource: returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, file-io, nsstring

I am attempting to access a .txt file from my supporting files folder in Xcode on iOS using the following piece of code:

```
NSString* filePath = @"filename.txt";

NSLog(@"File path: %@", filePath);

NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"txt"];

NSLog(@"File root: %@", fileRoot);
```

The first NSLog prints just what I expect it to print, but the last NSLog always simply prints

> File root: (null)

Accessing text from the file after (attempting to) reading it into memory also simply gives me a (null) printout.

The solution for this problem is probably right under my nose, I just can't seem to find it. Any help is very appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`filePath` already contains the suffix ".txt", therefore you must not specify it
again when locating the resource. Either

```
NSString* filePath = @"filename.txt";
NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:nil];
```

or

```
NSString* filePath = @"filename";
NSString* fileRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType:@"txt"];
```

Comment: That's it, thank you! I will accept the answer as soon as I am allowed to by SO.